# JavaScript-High charts(Spider-chart)

Tags: highcharts

I wants to add the points on my Y-axis and wants to display their values right next their respective X-axis(e.g MDMT, CPQC,NDLC... ). Is there any highchart attribute to accomplish that? .
[Please find graph as a reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxLyo.png)

Comment: Please explain more accurately what you're trying to accomplish (visual example would be ideal).

Comment: I wants to add data points(series points) that falls in an given  X-axis and wants to display next to X-axis label

Comment: Please share your code.